# Sorting only evens in an array while keeping the odds in place WITHOUT creating a new array

Tags: java, algorithm, sorting

Is there any way to do this?

Doing it with a separate array to hold and sort all of the evens is pretty trivial:

1. place all evens in a separate array
2. sort the array containing the evens
3. iterate through original array, replacing the even elements

But... I can't seem to find a way to do this without a separate array to hold the evens. Any tips?

Comment: Put every item from even index into a secondary array/list, sort it, then place the items back.

Comment: @ErvinSzilagyi - The Q asks ... without creating a new array.  And ArrayList has an array inside.  Creating *any* secondard datastructure to hold multiple elements is basically "cheating" ... and not a legitimate solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sure. I'm confident many of the standard in-place search algorithms can be modified, but insertion sort is particularly easy. The usual sort:

```
void sort(int *a, int size) {
  for (int s = 1; s < size; ++s) {
    int t = a[s], i;
    for (i = s; i > 0 && t < a[i - 1]; --i) a[i] = a[i - 1];
    a[i] = t;
  }
}
```

So here we do the same thing except with extra inserted loops to ignore odd entries.  This is a quick hack, very possibly with bugs remaining:

```
void sort_evens(int *a, int size) {
  int i, s;
  for (s = 0; s < size && a[s] % 2 == 1; ++s) /* skip */;
  if (s == size) return;

  while (1) {
    for (++s; s < size && a[s] % 2 == 1; ++s) /* skip */;
    if (s == size) return;
    int i_last = s, t = a[s];
    for (i = s - 1; i >= 0; --i) {
      for ( ; i >= 0 && a[i] % 2 == 1; --i) /* skip */;
      if (i < 0 || t >= a[i]) break;
      a[i_last] = a[i];
      i_last = i;
    }
    a[i_last] = t;
  }
}
```

On this data:

```
int a[] = {7,3,10,9,0,1,4,3,2,1,6,8,3,5,};
```

it produces

```
7 3 0 9 2 1 4 3 6 1 8 10 3 5
```

More fun would be heapsort.

Answer (score 1):

You would use any sorting algorithm and ignore the Odd ones.
Just swap values in-place without creating a new array.

```
for (int i = 0; i < input.length; i++)
{
    var cur = input[i];

    // ignore odd
    if (cur % 2 != 0)
        continue;

    var lowest = cur;
    var lowestIx = 0;

    // find the lowest value
    for (int j = i + 1; j < input.length; j++)
    {
        var next = input[j];
        
        // ignore odd
        if (next % 2 != 0)
            continue;

        if (next < lowest)
        {
            lowestIx = j;
            lowest = next;
        }
    }

    // swap with lowest
    if (lowest != cur)
    {
        var tmp = input[lowestIx];
        input[lowestIx] = input[i];
        input[i] = tmp;
    }
}
```